# Replace <table> with <div>, including width, and height

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm currently working on a project that uses tables, which is obviously not ideal but marketing "needs" it...

I'm using jQuery to convert all the tables to DIVs and it's working fine, but I need the width and height of the table, like this:

```
<table border="0" width="#1" height="#2">
```

to:

```
<div style="width:#1px; height:#2px">
```

This is my code to replace the tables, and it works. I just need to be able to add in the width and height from the table before I remove them.

```
$('table').replaceWith($('table').html()
        .replace(/<tbody/gi, "<div id='table'")
        .replace(/<tr/gi, "<div")
        .replace(/<\/tr>/gi, "</div>")
        .replace(/<td/gi, "<span")
        .replace(/<\/td>/gi, "</span>")
        .replace(/<\/tbody/gi, "<\/div")
);
```

**MY SOLUTION:**

```
    $('table').each(function () {
        var t = $(this);
        var w = t.width() + 'px';
        var h = t.height() + 'px';

        t.replaceWith(t.html()
            .replace(/<tbody/gi, "<div style='height:" + h + ";width:" + w +"' class='container'")
            .replace(/<tr/gi, "<div class='row'")
            .replace(/<\/tr>/gi, "</div>")
            .replace(/<td/gi, "<div class='col'")
            .replace(/<\/td>/gi, "</div>")
            .replace(/<\/tbody/gi, "<\/div")
        );

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save width and height then use it like:

```js
var $width = $('table').width();
var $height = $('table').height();
$('table').replaceWith($('table').html()
        .replace(/<tbody/gi, '<div id="table" style="width:'+$width+'px; height:'+$height+'px;" ')
        .replace(/<tr/gi, '<div')
        .replace(/<\/tr>/gi, '</div>')
        .replace(/<td/gi, '<span')
        .replace(/<\/td>/gi, '</span>')
        .replace(/<\/tbody/gi, '<\/div')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" width="#1" height="#2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

### jQuery

You can use `$.attr('width')` or `$.attr('height')`.

### Plain Javascript

You can use `Element.getAttribute()` for this.

e.g. `table.getAttribute('width');` and `table.getAttribute('height');`

Then once you got the width and height, you can use it on the `div` element.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Comment: That's what I ended up doing! Look at my chosen answer by Simone Rossaini

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be the easiest way if you don't manipulate it on the HTML source code level but on the object one. That makes things a lot easier. It should be possible to create a `div` element, then set its `style` to whatever you want it to be (in this case your given width and height you can just grab via JS) and then take all the child objects of the `table` and append them to your `div` element. In the worst case, just keep your code but first store the width and height somewhere (using `var w=document.getElementById('mytable').width`)and then copy them over to your `div` later.